# topojson.js:187: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: d3.js

I a trying to make a map with D3 and TopoJSON for the Netherlands, including the provinces.
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/webserver/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/webserver/topojson/topojson.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            div.bar {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 20px;
                height: 75px;
                background-color: teal;
                margin-right: 2px;
            }
            .pumpkin {
                fill: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.75);
                stroke: yellow;
                stroke-width: 5;
            }
            .apple {
                fill: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.55);
                stroke: green;
                stroke-width: 15;
            }
            .orange {
                fill: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.55);
                stroke: orange;
                stroke-width: 10;
            }
            .subunit    { fill: #cdc; }
            .subunit-label  {
                fill: #777;
                fill-opacity: .25;
                font-size:  30px;
                font-weight: 300;
                text-anchor: middle;}

            .provincie  {fill: none; }
            .Utrecht    {fill: #ddd; }
            .Zuid-Holland   {fill: #dde; }
            .Noord-Holland  {fill: #dee; }
            .Drenthe    {fill: #aae; }
            .Gelderland     {fill: #eee; }
            .Friesland  {fill: #ddc; }
            .Groningen  {fill: #dcc; }
            .Limburg    {fill: #ccc; }
            .Noord-Brabant  {fill: #ddb; }
            .Overijssel     {fill: #dbb; }
            .Zeeland    {fill: #bbb; }
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var width = 960, height = 860;

    var projection = d3.geo.albers()
        .center([6, 49.40])
        .rotate([0, -1.9])
        .parallels([50, 60])
        .scale(11000)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width) 
        .attr("height", height);

    d3.json("http://localhost/webserver/data/nl.json", function(error, nl) {
        svg.selectAll(".subunit")
        .data(topojson.object(nl, nl.objects.subunits).geometries)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path);

        svg.selectAll(".subunit-label")
        .data(topojson.object(nl, nl.objects.subunits).geometries)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", -20)
        .attr("y", -50)
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit-label " + d.id; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });

        svg.selectAll(".provincie")
        .data(topojson.object(nl, nl.objects.provincies).geometries)
        .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "provincie " + d.properties.name; })
        .attr("d", path);

        svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.object(nl, nl.objects.places))
        .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "place");

        svg.selectAll(".place-label")
        .data(topojson.object(nl, nl.objects.places).geometries)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "place-label")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.coordinates) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });

        svg.selectAll(".place-label")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 10 : -10; })
            .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.coordinates[0] > -1 ? "start" : "end"; });
        }); 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result is the map of the Netherlands, however it doesn't contain the provinces (with colors and borders).

I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined topojson.js:187

This is line 186 and 187:

function geometry(o) {

var t = o.type, g = t === "GeometryCollection" ? {type: t, geometries: o.geometries.map(geometry)}

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you are referencing an object that doesn't exist in your topology.

Is it possible your TopoJSON file uses the English spelling of "provinces" rather than the Dutch "provincies"? If it did, then `nl.objects.provincies` would be null, and you'd either need to refer to `nl.objects.provinces` in your code, or edit the TopoJSON file to use the Dutch spelling "provincies" instead.

Can you post the contents of nl.json so we can take a look (say, on dropbox)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer mbostock. I just found out there was a problem with the nl.json file and that solved the issue.

Comment: That's funny. I'm trying to show a TopoJSON file for Gelderland (a province in The Netherlands), but there might be a problem in that file as well. What was the problem in your `nl.json` file, @csnake?